# Is chmod 060/006/066/etc... useful?

Tags: unix, permissions

Are there any useful applications of `chmod 060`, `chmod 006` or similar permissions?

I wonder, why in `chmod UGO`, there are no restrictions such as U >= G >= O? Is is just simpler to implement it this way, or is there some other use case intended for it?

My main motivation is to teach permissions for Unix newbies, so I'm trying to impose constraints to minimize the number of possibilities and simplify the explanations.

Comment: The command is useful to implement the bit mask. You seem to be asking (but not really asking) if there is a situation wherein that specific permission configuration is useful. Is that really what you are looking for?

Comment: +1, good question. Scanned for masks of the type 0x0 and 00x with 0< x <8, on Debian, Kubuntu, Arch, OpenBSD, FreeBSD, could not find a single file of the sort.

Comment: Please clarify what you are really asking - is it `chmod 060` vs. `chmod u=,g=rw,o=` ? Or is it about the special values `060`?

Answer (score 2):

You can always imagine possible scenarios. For example, `060` (group has read/write access and no one else can do anything) could be useful if you have a webserver creating a file but you don't want it to be able to then overwrite it or otherwise access it. So, you make the file belong to a particular group, allow users of that group to manipulate it and no one else.

I suppose I similar situation might arise for `006` where everyone can write but not the owner/group. I can only imagine these masks being useful in cases where the file's owner is not a regular user (webserver or daemon or whatever).

Remember that permissions are hierarchical. So, if you're the owner of a file with `006` permissions, you cannot write to it, despite the fact that "everyone" can:

```
terdon@localhost $ touch file; chmod 006 file; ls -l file
-------rw- 1 terdon terdon 8 Feb 10 17:24 file
terdon@localhost $ echo "foo" > file
bash: file: Permission denied
terdon@localhost su bob
bob@localhost $ echo "foo" > file
bob@localhost $
```

So, even `006` stops the owner from accessing the file which, as I said, could come in handy in certain setups.